# c# command pattern design issue

Tags: c#, undo-redo, command-pattern

Dears,

I have object model whose members' (objects') properties can be changed by PropertyGrid and UI (PopupMenu etc). I am looking for support UndoRedo in this case and interested design of Command Pattern. AS I understand, changing any property via PropertyGrid should be registered in UndoRedo stack, however, Undoing this operation is equals to changing that property to old value - and Infinite Loop? Do you know any best practice in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: I was wondering if you could rephrase your question as it is not really clear to me as to what it is that you are looking for exactly. Are you trying to understand how you should implement the command pattern for undo/redo implementation? If you already have some sort of implementation I would like to see it so I can better understand how far you are in implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the Undo action doesn't have to be count as a change.

You have a collection of your changes. When you make a change you add an item in this collection. If you make an undo you just swap the current state with [i-1] state. If you make a redo you swap the current state with [i+1] state. If you have made some Undo's and then make a change you start to write from there and rewrite all possible Redo's.